# Is it possible to publish messages using Google Nearby Messages in the background in Android?

Tags: android, google-nearby

I am developing an app,which is publishing messages and subscribe using Google Nearby Messages API.The documentation says **Because the Nearby Messages APIs have the potential to impact battery life, they should only be used from a foreground activity (with the exception of BLE background subscribe).**

But is it still possible?

And what strategy to use to achieve maximum distance?

Thx.

Answer (score 1):

Answer to your question, [on the official documentation](https://developers.google.com/nearby/messages/android/get-beacon-messages#subscribe_in_the_background)

Sample [GitHub Google](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-nearby/tree/master/messages/NearbyDevices)

## Google Solution

```
// Subscribe to messages in the background.
private void backgroundSubscribe() {
    Log.i(TAG, "Subscribing for background updates.");
    SubscribeOptions options = new SubscribeOptions.Builder()
            .setStrategy(Strategy.BLE_ONLY)
            .build();
    Nearby.getMessagesClient(this).subscribe(getPendingIntent(), options);
}

private PendingIntent getPendingIntent() {
    return PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, new Intent(this, BeaconMessageReceiver.class),
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
}
```

The following code snippet demonstrates handling the intent in the BeaconMessageReceiver class.

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Nearby.getMessagesClient(context).handleIntent(intent, new MessageListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFound(Message message) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Found message via PendingIntent: " + message);
        }

        @Override
        public void onLost(Message message) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Lost message via PendingIntent: " + message);
        }
    });
}
```

When the subscription is no longer required, your app should unsubscribe by calling Nearby.getMessagesClient(Activity).unsubscribe(PendingIntent).

## A solution to use BLE

```
SubscribeOptions.Builder builder = new SubscribeOptions.Builder();

if (getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_BLUETOOTH_LE)) {
    builder.setStrategy(Strategy.BLE_ONLY);
} else {
    builder.setStrategy(new Strategy.Builder().setDistanceType(Strategy.DISTANCE_TYPE_EARSHOT).build());
    Toast.makeText(this, "BLE NOT SUPPORTED", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

mOptions = builder.build();
```

## Publish

```
Strategy s = new Strategy.Builder()
                    .setDistanceType(Strategy.DISTANCE_TYPE_EARSHOT)
                    .build();
PublishOptions options = new PublishOptions.Builder()
                                .setStrategy(s)
                                .build();
Nerby.getMessagesClient(this).publish(mMessageName, options);
```